# How to send notification using fcm larger than 4kb

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing messaging app in ios, android and web platforms. We want to send a large chat message(text) from the server to clients(Web, android, ios). But data messages can have a 4KB maximum payload when sending push notification using FCM as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).

An immediate workaround would be to divide a large message into chunks of 4KB and send all those notification. Any better suggestion other than this solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Have the message contain a secure URL or other identifying information to pull the full data from the server. IOW, the push message does not contain the chat message, but contains information about how to obtain the chat message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate the message and make your own message type that contains information about how many parts and it's part number, then assign an id to the whole message, send them through FCM, in the client, you can collect received messages until all parts will arrive, and then combine all of them to get final message, I am using this solution.
it's working believe me